# How to specify font size in different div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to specify the font size of my `div` inside a parent `div` as same as the `div` outside of the parent `div`..

I have

html

```
<div id='parent' >
 <div class='testclass'><b>title</b><br> contents here</div>

</div>

 <div class='testclass'><b>title2</b><br> contents here</div>
 <div class='testclass'><b>title3</b><br> contents here</div>
 <div class='testclass'><b>title4</b><br> contents here</div>
```

My css

```
parent{
font-size:.8em;font-weight:bold;
}

.testclass{
font-size:1.1em
}
```

The `div` outside of the parent `div` have correct font size (`1.1em`), but the font size inside parent `div` is smaller than outside `div`. However, if I specify 15px instead of em in my `testclass`. everything works fine. 
Any ways to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe it's too subtle for me to notice a difference but they all look the same here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DHus3/

Comment: That's because OP made a typo when distilling/anonymizing his code: the `parent` selector should be `#parent`. Correct that in your fiddle and you'll see his problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that your CSS rule for the parent is actually:

```
#parent {
    font-size:.8em;font-weight:bold;
}
```

in which case this makes sense. You have two simple ways to make `.testclass` override `#parent#'s selector:

- Make another, more specific selector for `testclass` like `#parent .testclass, .testclass {...}`
- Make the font-size declaration in `.testclass` override with the **!important** flag: `.testclass{ font-size:1.1em !important;}`

Comment: But you should generally avoid using `!important`.

Comment: Agreed. That's why it was the second option.

Answer (score 0):

+1 Sudowned. But also in IE7/FF3.6 up you can also use `>` to specify a first level child. So the following will also target the correct div

```
#parent > div {
    font-size:.8em;font-weight:bold;
}
```

or even

```
#parent > .testclass {
    font-size:.8em;font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`em`s are relative.
What I mean is that they stack, sort of like percentages.

If you say:

```
body { font-size : 20px; }

#parent { font-size : 2em; }
#child  { font-size : 3em; }
```

What you're actually doing is saying (note that ems don't exactly mean px-- they mean the M-measurement, but for all intent and purpose, it's practically the same thing here):

```
Body = 20px;
Parent = Body * 2; //200% of the M-measurement of Body's font-size.
Child = Parent * 3; // 300% of the M-measurement of Parent's font-size,
                // which would be 600% of Body at this point
```

Instead, what you might be looking for is:

```
Body = 20px;
Parent = Body * X;
Child =  Parent * 1/X;
```

ex:

```
Body = 20px;
Parent = 2em;  // 40px, effectively
Child = 0.5em; // This 0.5 is referring to half of Parent's em
               // As the parent was 2x body, this sets Child to body's height


Body = 15px;
Parent = 0.8em;  // 15 * 0.8 = 12
Child = 1.25em;  // 12 * 1.25 = 15
```

The CSS3 solution is to use `rem`s.  Not the band.
`rem`s are ***ALWAYS*** relative to the root.

So if you set:

```
Child = 1rem;
```

It will be equal to 100% of the document's base-size, regardless of what its parent (or grandparents) is set to (and then you can use `em` to relatively size elements under Child).

Note that this is CSS3, and so while FireFox and Chrome have wide support for `rem`, it's only IE9+.

That's why I suggested the math-primer as well.